# How do I cleanly shutdown mongodb from node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running mongodb as a child process from node.js and require to shut down and restart on demand.  using Child_Process.kill("SIGINT") would appear to be the correct way but but it leaves mongo in a confused state which won't restart until repaired (or the lockfile is deleted)   Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Doing `kill("SIGINT")` cause the database to shut down without going through the required steps  and could lead to corrupt data files. So i would not recommend do this.

Normal way to stop database is send command `{ "shutdown" : 1 }` or `db.shutdownServer()` from mongodb shell, but I don't know exactly how to do it from node.js driver.

Comment: From the Mongodb documentation:
Sending a Unix INT or TERM signal
You can cleanly stop mongod using a SIGINT or SIGTERM signal on Unix-like systems. Either ^C, "kill -2 PID," or kill -15 PID will work.

 Sending a KILL signal kill -9 will probably cause damage if mongod is not running with the --journal option.  (In such a scenario, run repairDatabase command.) 


Is there an equivalent operation for windows?

Comment: Correction: according to the [stop mongod processes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes) documentation, it is *safe* to stop mongod by sending it a SIGINT (signal 2) or a SIGTERM (signal 15, the default signal).  These are listed among a series of different safe ways to shut down mongo.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/admin", function(err, db) {
 if (err) {
  console.log('mongodb is not running');
  process.exit(0);
 }
 else {
  db.command({
   shutdown : 1
  }, function(err, result) {
   console.log('shutting down mongodb - ', err.message);
   process.exit(0);
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could end a mongodb process using nodeJS on mac

1) save the script below to a script.js

```
'use strict'
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;
function killport(port) {
    var processId = null
    try {
        processId = exec(`lsof -t -i:${port}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("could not catch");
    }
    if (processId !== null) { // if exists kill
       try{
           if(exec(`kill ${processId}`)){
               console.log("closed");
            }
       } catch(e){
            console.log("error executing");
       }
     }
  }
 killport(27017);
```

2) run node script.js